# Algorithmic complexity of this algorithm to find all ordered permutations of length X

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, permutation

I have written a recursive function to generate the list of all ordered permutations of length X for a list of chars.

For instance: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] with X=2 will give [['a', 'a'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['a', 'd'], ['b', 'a'], ['b', 'b'], ..., ['d', 'd']]

I'm not sure about its algorithmic complexity though (at least I know it's pretty horrible). I would say it's something around:

O(X * N^(L + X))

(where L is the number of different chars, 4 here because we have 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', and X the length of the permutations we want to generate).
Because I have 2 nested loops, which will be run X times (well, X-1 because of the special case when X = 1).
Is it correct?

```
def generate_permutations(symbols, permutations_length):
    if permutations_length == 1:
        return [[symbol] for symbol in symbols]

    tails = generate_permutations(symbols, permutations_length-1)
    permutations = []

    for symbol in symbols:
        for tail in tails:
            permutation = [symbol] + tail

            permutations.append(permutation)

    return permutations


print(generate_permutations(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2))
```

By the way: I know this is not idiomatic Python and I apologize if it's ugly but it's just some prototyping I'm doing before writing this code in a different, less expressive language.
And I also know that I could use itertools.permutations to do this task. By the way, I'd be interested if someone happens to know the algorithmic complexity of itertool's permutations function, and if there is some way to improve the complexity of my own algorithm.

Thanks!

Comment: I think this question should be asked in Code Review Section Here : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi! I'm not sure about the difference between codereview.stackexchange.com and stackoverflow. Do you think here is not the right place?

Comment: The difference is you want your code reviewed. Meaning you want to know if your code is Performant and Clean and if it can be improved. Code Review Stack is for that only.

Comment: Actually, I don't want to know if my code is clean or can be improved (I'm sure it can), I'm only interested in its logarithmic complexity.

Comment: That is reviewing @Matthieu You will get more response there.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll post there too then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of steps for generating when `X`=1 is:

```
N(1) = L
```

At the recursive step, the number of steps is the number of steps at `X-1`, due to recursive call, plus `L * N(X-1)` due to the loops:

```
N(X) = N(X-1) + L * N(X-1)
```

Clearly `L * N(X-1)` dominates `N(X-1)`, so we can disregard the `N(X-1)` term.

The asymptotic cost will be **O(L^X)**.

L<sup>X</sup> happens to be also the number of the items in the result, so it's impossible that you have a better asymptotic cost for that using python lists.

Comment: Thanks!
But to be honest, I don't understand why the loops give a complexity of L * N(X-1).

And do you know if there are better algorithms out there without lists at you seem to suggest?

Comment: just think about how many items are in `tails`. then you have nested for loops iterating `symbols` and `tails`, so the number of steps is the product of the lengths of those two.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically, number of all the ordered permutations itself is equal to  **<sup>L</sup>P<sub>X</sub>** as explained on the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#k-permutations_of_n).

<sup>L</sup>P<sub>X</sub> `= L*(L-1)*..*(L-X+1)`

which is approximately equal to L<sup>X</sup>.

Now, each final permutation of length `X` is produced step-by-step by adding one character at a time in the existing string length, i.e., total complexity worth `O(1+2+3+..+X)`, or **O(X<sup>2</sup>)**.

Finally, your python implementation is actually an example of optimal recursion and takes the algorithmic complexity of **O(X<sup>2</sup> * <sup>L</sup>P<sub>X</sub>)**